# Why does safari sometimes fail to respond to CSS quickly?

Tags: css, safari, browser-cache

I have lost development time adjusting CSS with some - but not all - results when checking at Safari. Some results is much worst than no results in terms of productivity, thus this question. All results do show on the next day or so (based on cache refresh maybe). I see suggestions to clear cache but nothing conclusive. Is there a permanent fix to solve that? Maybe a script to clean cache again and again?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what your issue is. If you want to clear the cache, press Ctrl + F5.

Comment: Hi @Celsiuss, CSS on my Python-Flask app don't show on Safari sometimes. I wish I did not have to bother with this - as on Firefox

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that might cause this: server cache, local cache even performance plugins if you use something like Wordpress.

Finding the exact cause needs more information from your side. But, even in the most extreme cases, there is one solution that you can use and it works almost every time for me: add a get parameter when including the .css file and change it when you make changes (style.css -> style.css?something=3123131, change the number every time).
You can do it in the files or you can even do it in developer tools, find the tag with the file and add the parameter manually there, the file willreload and you'll see the latest changes.

EDIT: this is a hack, use it when you can't control the cache or changes are small and it would be more time consuming to setup the system than to use this hack.

Comment: You can even do it in javascript after DOM is ready, by finding the dom element with the css file and add a get parameter.

Comment: Thanks @heraphim, I'm inclined to continue to test on other browsers for the moment. I will add a get parameter if the problem continues - still time consuming but some hope

Comment: Tip: (in case you don't know) in Chrome open developer tools (CTRL + SHIFT + i), right click the refresh icon on the left of the address bar and click "Clear Cache and Hard Reload" for a full local cache clear.